# What am I doing wrong? Finding a limit as $x$ approaches $0$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\over x^2} =$$

$${a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\over x^2}\cdot{a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\over a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} = $$

$$a^{2} - a^{2} - x^{2}\over ax^{2} + x^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}} $$

$$-x^{2}\over ax^{2}+x^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}$$

$$-1\over a+\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}$$

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: $a^2 - (a^2-x^2) = x^2$

Comment: Check your algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be 
$${a^{2} - (a^{2} - x^{2})\over ax^{2} + x^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}=
{a^{2} - a^{2} +x^{2}\over ax^{2} + x^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Third equality $$\left (a - \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\right )\left (a+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}\right ) \color{blue}{=x^2}$$